# How to put Database Tables in MVC Models

Tags: database, model-view-controller, model

I'm new in developing in MVC and I have some doubts in how to build the Models. I don't know if I must build them in terms of Database Tables or in other terms.

I have for example this 5 tables:

- Domain
- Category_Domains
- Countries_Domains
- Categories
- Countries

How can i Build a Models to do actions in these Database Tables. Should I built the SQL commands to Insert, Delete and Update for each one of these Tables or I should do other thing than this?

Sorry if I not explain well.

Answer (score 0):

The best advice I can give you is to look into the entity framework. Using this framework, you can create a data connection to your SQL database and the framework will create your model based on your table structure, including relationships.

Doing this will ensure your database is modelled correctly and kept in sync at all times

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I'm not using .NET, I'm using PHP. The Entity Framework is an ORM? Best Regards

Comment: Apologies, I thought I had filtered by .Net.. Good luck